# Looking for a regex that will find a word or words following an IP address

Tags: regex, grep

Given a line of the following structure
ID: '560'",,10.117.219.156,Browser,fa7a0434-8f0a-47f2-a3ea-3864d652a042,NAME:

I wish to extract the word or words following the IP address (any IP) and ',' upto the following ','. In this example the returned word would be "Browser".

Here is the best I've come up with thus far: `(?<=,)(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+),\w+(?=,)`

The expression above does a positive lookbehind for a 'comma', followed by capturing groups resembling an IP address "(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)", followed by a 'comma', then the word(s) of interest, followed by a 'comma'.

The problem is that the regex returns the IP address, which i **don't** want. Here is what i'm getting back when i run: `grep -Po '(?<=,)(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+),\w+(?=,)' /c/tmp/BB1.csv`

```
10.117.245.154,Browser
10.123.33.66,PyCharm IDE
10.117.245.123,Calculator HP
```

What I want returned is:
Browser
PyCharm IDE
Calculator HP

Comment: Use `\K`, `grep -Po ',\d+(?:\.\d+){3},\K\w+(?=,)'` (although I am not sure this is the exact regex you are using as `\w` does not match spaces). Maybe instead of `\w` use `[^,]+`. Try `,\d+(?:\.\d+){3},\K[^,]+`, see https://regex101.com/r/pnPahK/1

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for **that** sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Learned something new. Did not know about \K, but that did the trick.

Why don't you provide that as an answer so that i can mark the question answered?

Comment: I'm still learning with you @WiktorStribiżew. Thanks for the \K !

Comment: @VincentFlotron I added an answer with a link to the `\K` reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```bash
grep -Po ',\d+(?:\.\d+){3},\K[^,]+' /c/tmp/BB1.csv
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pnPahK/1). *Details*:

- `,` - a comma
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+){3}` - three occurrences of `.` and then one or more digits
- `,` - a comma
- `\K` - [*match reset operator*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that discards all text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `[^,]+` - one or more chars other than a comma.

Comment: Note the use of escaped dots.

Comment: @PoulBak It is not necessary, OP [has them escaped well](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4ae03ff7-d2c8-4c8c-a366-d0a5236f1e12/view-source).

Comment: Ah, I see, I edited the question to include code blocks to prevent misunderstandings.